# Supressing Jetty output during Ant build

Tags: ant, junit, jetty

I'm creating an ant script to do some integration testing for a small project.  The application in question is a web application packaged as a WAR.  Currently, my ant script generates a WAR file, launches Jetty with the packaged WAR file, and then runs my Selenium based unit tests against the server application.  Everything is working so far.

My problem is that the Jetty ant plugin generates a huge amount of logging output to the terminal.  I'd really like to change the logging level for Jetty, but I can't figure out how. I've tried changing jetty logging system properties in two different ways, and neither worked.  First by including `<systemproperty>` elements in the ant file, and second by setting them using `ant_opts` (That is, I've set `ANT_OPTS="-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=WARN -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StrErrLog"`)

I'm running the server in daemon mode so that it will run alongside my testing targets.  So, although I was able to turn off logging in the jetty.run target itself, that also turned off logging in the test target, and if I turned it back on in the test target, then all jetty output during the test is still written to the terminal.  Also, all Jetty output during the test target is labelled as [junit], since it's being output during the test target.

I want to lower the logging level for Jetty to WARN (which really ought to be the default for the plugin) and I cannot figure out how.  I've included the relevant parts of the build script.

```xml
<target name="jetty.run" depends="build-and-package">

    <typedef name="webApp" classname="org.eclipse.jetty.ant.AntWebAppContext" classpathref="classpath" loaderref="jetty.loader" onerror="ignore" />
    <taskdef classpathref="classpath" resource="tasks.properties" loaderref="jetty.loader" />

    <jetty.run daemon="true">
        <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty name="org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL" value="WARN" />
            <systemProperty name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class" value="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StrErrLog" />
        </systemProperties>
        <webApp war="${artifacts}/${warfilename}" contextPath="/" />
    </jetty.run>
</target>

<target name="test" depends="compile-tests, jetty.run">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}" />
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr" haltonfailure="yes" haltonerror="yes">
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${compiled-tests.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test*" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
        <classpath path="${compiled-classes.dir}" />
        <classpath path="${compiled-tests.dir}" />
    </junit>
</target>
```

**Edit** Here is some (very trimmed) sample output starting from the jetty.run task.  I am trying to eliminate all or most of the non-junit output

```
jetty.run:
[jetty.run] Daemon=true
[jetty.run] 2015-02-02 14:47:47.671:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2789ms
[jetty.run] Configuring Jetty for project: Build script for Vaadin 7 projects
[jetty.run] Setting property 'org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL' to value 'WARN'
[jetty.run] Setting property 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class' to value 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StrErrLog'
[jetty.run] 2015-02-02 14:47:47.757:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.7.v20150116
[jetty.run] 2015-02-02 14:47:47.769: Starting web application null
[jetty.run] 2015-02-02 14:47:48.759:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
[jetty.run] 2015-02-02 14:47:48.794:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.a.AntWebAppContext@cad498c{/,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-card_trainer.war-_-any-2642472331853673434.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{build/card_trainer.war}
[jetty.run] 2015-02-02 14:47:48.795:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
[jetty.run] 2015-02-02 14:47:48.807:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6c5a7edc{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[jetty.run] 2015-02-02 14:47:48.808:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @3929ms
[jetty.run] Jetty AntTask Started

test:
[junit] WARNING: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit 
[junit]          jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
[junit]      and jar:file:/home/dyule/git/card_trainer/ivy_libs/nodeploy/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
[junit] Running com.example.card_trainer.CardSourceTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.126 sec
[junit] Running com.example.card_trainer.Card_trainerTest
[junit] Feb 02, 2015 2:47:51 PM 
[junit] Feb 02, 2015 2:47:51 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addAtmosphereHandler
[junit] INFO: Installed AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler$1 mapped to context-path: /*
[junit] Feb 02, 2015 2:47:51 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework addAtmosphereHandler
[junit] INFO: Installed the following AtmosphereInterceptor mapped to AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler$1
[junit] Feb 02, 2015 2:47:51 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework doInitParams
[junit] WARNING: SessionSupport error. Make sure you define org.atmosphere.cpr.SessionSupport as a listener in web.xml instead
[junit] Feb 02, 2015 2:47:51 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework autoConfigureService
[junit] INFO: Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
[junit] Feb 02, 2015 2:47:51 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor configure
[junit] INFO: AnnotationProcessor class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor$ServletContainerInitializerAnnotationProcessor being used
[junit] Feb 02, 2015 2:47:51 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor fallbackToManualAnnotatedClasses
[junit] WARNING: Unable to detect annotations. Application may fail to deploy.
[junit] Feb 02, 2015 2:47:51 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework autoDetectWebSocketHandler
[junit] INFO: Auto detecting WebSocketHandler in /WEB-INF/classes/
[junit] Feb 02, 2015 2:47:51 PM org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework initWebSocket
[junit] INFO: Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol
```

Comment: I've read your question 3 times, and I have a hard time following what desired end result you are aiming for.  Mainly I'm trying to understand how `<junit>` has any care or relevance about Jetty logging, as your junit tests should not be using Jetty's internal Logging implementation.  Those would be on a different Logging infrastructure and be completely  unrelated to Jetty Logging.

Comment: I agree that the JUnit tests should not care about jetty logging, but for some reason, jetty logging is happening during JUnit tests, I suspect because jetty's being run in daemon mode.  I shall attach some sample output shortly

Comment: The atmosphere logging appears to be from java.util.logging, and the jetty logging isn't using your `<systemProperties>` (as those properties are set too late for the logging to pick them up)

Comment: I also tried setting them as ANT_OPTS, so they would be present for the whole ant script, but no such luck.  Is there a way I can set them?  Like maybe directly as system properties in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

From ant script - Its true that you are using Default Logging for Jetty
**StdErrLog**.

Of course, this will throws all the logging to Terminal (STDOUT, STDERR)

You can capture its content to a file -

Capturing Console Output to File

logging module in Jetty distribution that is capable of performing simple capturing of all STDOUT and STDERR output to a file.

add "--module=logging" to $JETTY_HOME/start.ini file

For More info: [Default Logging with Jetty's StdErrLog](http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/default-logging-with-stderrlog.html)

Configuring StdErrLog

The recommended way to configure StdErrLog is to create a ${jetty.home}/resources/jetty-logging.properties file, specify the Log implementation to StdErrLog and then setup your logging levels.

-Hope this may be helpful

Comment: That only applies to using the jetty-distribution, which jetty ant does not.